# Get random app details from Steam API

Tags: php, json, steam

I'm trying to build a script which gives me a random game from steam and its details.

My first thoughts were that I get a JSON from all apps via
    https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/

Then I get a random AppId from it.

With http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=RANDOMAPPID I get the details from it.

But not all apps from the list are in the store. So in most cases I get nothing and I have to search for another app. 
The problem is I can only do 200 requests in 5 minutes. Mostly I don't get any app details in that time.

Is there any other way I can do to get a random app + details?

I'm just using PHP and JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Always wondering why someone gives downvotes instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to give you an idea: This array_column function gives array with specified column values.We must pass double dimension array.

```
function arrayColumn(array $array, $column_key, $index_key = null) {
        $result = array ();
        foreach ( $array as $arr ) {
            if (! is_array ( $arr ))
                continue;

            if (is_null ( $column_key )) {
                $value = $arr;
            } else {
                $value = $arr [$column_key];
            }

            if (! is_null ( $index_key )) {
                $key = $arr [$index_key];
                $result [$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $result [] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $result;
}




$apps_data = reponse of this service https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/

$app_ids_array = arrayColumn($apps_data['applist']['apps'],'appid');

$random_app_ids = array_rand($app_ids_array,100);

foreach($random_app_ids as $app_id){
Hit this service http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=$app_id 
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for you answer.

My mainproblem is that I only get the info if the app is in the store or not, when I request the infos from the store and not via the api. 

And thats the wrong way, because I can't send requests to the store everytime.

Maybe there is another way over the api?